# Node Red, Http request with authorization : bearer

Tags: javascript, http, node-red

im a newbie with NodeRed.

I am trying to create a `http request` for the Actility `LORAWAN` platform with the authorization : `bearer token without success`.

The request is working and i get

```
{
  "code" : 401,
  "message" : "Permission denied: Authorization header must be set with Bearer token",
  "errorId" : null
}
```

I have tried to find some information of how to do the function node with a authorization : bearer in javascript but i cant find any examples of code?

Can someone help me with an example of how to do a proper code and connect the function node together with an http request node?

Kind regards

Andreas Hauser

Answer (score 0):

here's an example for you, given that you are sending JSON & expecting a JSON response

```
const request = require('request-promise');

request({
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: 'Bearer <YOUR_BEARER_TOKEN_HERE>',
  },
  json: true,
  uri: 'http://localhost:<PORT>/more-url',
  method: 'POST',
  body: { foo: 'bar' }
})
.then(function (result) {
  // do something with result
});
```

Comment: Hi Theo, and thank you for your code. It didnt work and i really dont know if im doing this right. Im trying to call the actility platform through node red with a timestamp, then i add a function node, i add your script there and then do a http request for the thinkpark http adress that have the device. i get the error "ReferenceError: require is not defined (line 1, col 17)" when i add your script in node red

Comment: Of course you should `npm install request-promise -S` first. Try again and dont forget to change `<YOUR_BEARER_TOKEN_HERE>` with the required  `bearer token` from `actility platform`

Comment: can i ask a new maybe more newbie question?.. the actility platform is generating 2 things. one http link with the device eui but one curl x command with the authorization bearer included. curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer xxxxxx . is there anyway i can include the script in a function from NODE red?

Comment: well im banging my head in the wall here, cant get the request work even though i added the npm file. till get the answer reference error require is not defined

Comment: Hi @AndreasHauser, you can ask that other question on another thread so it could be answered properly. what node version are you using? can you post more details on the error in a gist or somewhere & post link here so we can debug further?

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the auth param this way for a bearer token

```
 var options = {
   url: APIURL,
   headers: {
     'User-Agent': 'client'
   },
   auth: {
     'bearer': accessToken
   }
 };
```